# CORS error with OKTA on Angular application

Tags: angular, okta, okta-api

I am using OKTA in my angular 12 application. I have setup the "Users", "Factors" and "Devices" with the same configuration inside the angular application but the "factors" and "devices" api are giving me CORS error. Users api works correctly. I have tested the collection in POSTMAN and it works fine there. I an using http://localhost:4200/ to access the application and it has been added to trusted list in OKTA admin.
Any clue why the "Users" api works while the "Devices" and "Factors" api don't?

Request URL: https://my-app-dev.oktapreview.com/api/v1/devices
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: of course you followed the actions described here: https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-spa-redirect/angular/main/#enable-trusted-origins

Comment: @CharlieV... yes I did. And I think my angular setup is correct because one of the OKTA api ( Users api ) is working fine. The other 2 ( Factors and Devices ) api are not working.